# Optimize call option purchase

Tags: options, black-scholes, binomial-tree

If it is predicted that the price of a stock will increase from P1 to between P2 and P3 in time T (assume the distribution of the price will be evenly distributed between the range of [P2, P3] at time T), how to optimize to find the best call option to purchase to maximize the profit?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the options available to you are priced using the Black-Scholes model and because your predicted prices of the stock at time $T$ are evenly distributed between $P_2$ and $P_3$ where $P_3 \ge P_2$, you should simply take the option with the strike price $K = P_2$ (or any lowest available).

This is because the fee (price) for a call option decreases more slowly than its strike price increases. Any call option with a strike price higher than the lowest available will cost you more in gross profit than it saves on the fee under these assumptions.

You can see how the price of a call option typically changes (decreases) as the strike price increases in the middle left chart below where $S_0$ is the stock's current price, $r$ is the risk-free interest rate, $\sigma$ is the stock's volatility, and $T$ is the time from today in years. The figure is from page 258 of the ninth edition (2018) of the "Options, Futures, and Other Derivatives" by John C. Hull.

[image: Effect of changes in stock price, strike price, and expiration date on option prices]

I guess a better proof of this recommendation would be to show, using calculus, that the first differential of a call option's price with respect to its strike price, under normal conditions, is always greater than $-1$ with the Black-Scholes model but that's beyond me.

Comment: The Black-Scholes formula is for European options. What should be used for US options?

Comment: LOL you mean American Options

Comment: IMO, same argument holds for American options.